# Trouble with C program that reads a MIPS instructions, outputs file with line number, and summary

Tags: c, mips

The problem: Use a c program to read a MIPS instruction file, output it to a second file (both are command line arguments) which contains the contents of the MIPS file, with line numbers. The second half is supposed to display a cross reference table, which details the identifier, the definition(a number), and the usage of that identifier, by line number, for any identifier used more than once.

Unfortunately, I've run aground, and the program not only doesnt seem to actually print anything, but it doesnt seem to make any files either. This is a bit of a last ditch effort, to see if anyone else can help me out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Func line takes in a file, and places a line number at the beginning of every
non blank line */

void line(FILE *input, FILE *output) {  
    char a, c;
    int lineNum = 0;
    int startOfLine = 1;
    char ch;
    fprintf(output, "%d  ", ++lineNum);

    //copy the contents of the input file into the output file
    do {
        a = fgetc(input);
        fputc(a, output);
        c = getc(input);
        if(a == '\n' && c != '\n') {
            if(lineNum > 9) 
                fprintf(output, "%d  ", ++lineNum);
            else 
                fprintf(output, "%d   ", ++lineNum);
        }
        ungetc(c, input);
    } while (a != EOF);
    printf("ran line: \n");
}

/* Func cross takes in a file, and finds each identifier, marks its definition, and every
use and returns that in the output file */

void cross(FILE *input, FILE *output) { 
    FILE *temp = fopen("temp.txt", "a+"); 
    int lineNum = 0;
    int startOfLine = 1;
    char identifier[20][10];
    char a, c, i;
    int j, k, p;
    int size=0;
    int def[20];
    int use[20][50];
    char tempstr[80];
    fprintf(output, "Identifier\tDefinition\t  Use\n");

    fprintf(temp, "%d   ", ++lineNum);
    //copy contents of input into a temp file
    do {
        a = fgetc(input);
        fputc(a, temp);
        c = getc(input);
        if(a == '\n' && c != '\n') {
            if(lineNum > 9) 
                fprintf(temp, "%d  ", ++lineNum);
            else 
                fprintf(temp, "%d   ", ++lineNum);
        }
        ungetc(c, input);
    } while (a != EOF);

    fclose(temp);
    fopen("temp.txt", "r");

    j=0;

    //checks to see if current line has an Identifier and if so saves it to an array
    //along with the line number it was defined on
    while(fgets(tempstr, 80, temp)) {
        if(isalpha(tempstr[4]) || tempstr[4] == '_') {
            sscanf(tempstr, "%d   %[0-9_A-Z_a-z_]", &def[j], identifier[j]);
            j++;
            size++;
        }
    }

    fclose(temp);
    fopen("temp.txt", "r");

    //checks for each identifier, on every line whether or not that identifier is used 
    while(fgets(tempstr, 80, temp)) {
        char *tempNum;
        sscanf(tempstr, "%s", tempNum);
        int tempN = atoi(tempNum);
        int n;
        p=0;
        for(n=0; n<size; n++) {
            if(strstr(tempstr, identifier[n]) && tempN > def[n] && tempstr[4] != '#') { 
                use[n][p] = tempN;
                p++;
            }
        }
    }

    //writes the identifier, definition, and uses to the file
    for(k=0;k<size;k++) {
        fprintf(output, "%s\t\t   %d\t\t  ", identifier[k], def[k]);
        for(p=0; p<50; p++) {
            if(use[k][p] != NULL && use[k][p] < lineNum && use[k][p] > def[k])
                fprintf(output,"%d ", use[k][p]);
        }
        fprintf(output, "\n");
    }
    printf("ran cross: \n");
} 

/*Func both returns the file with numbered lines and a cross reference table at the bottom of the file */

void both(FILE *input, FILE *output, char *outputName) {    
    FILE *lineFile = fopen("line.txt", "a+");
    FILE *crossFile = fopen("cross.txt", "a+");
    char ch;
    line(input, lineFile);
    cross(input, crossFile);
    while( (ch = fgetc(lineFile)) != EOF)
        fputc(ch, output);
    fprintf(output, "\n\t\t\tCross Reference Table\n");
    while( (ch = fgetc(crossFile)) != EOF)
        fputc(ch, output);
    fclose(output);
    printf("ran both: \n");
} 

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    FILE *input, *output;
    output = fopen(argv[4], "a+"); 
    char outputName[50];
    strcpy(outputName, argv[4]);

    //Error testing
    if(argc > 5)
        exit(1);
    if(strcmp(argv[2], "-l") != 0 && strcmp(argv[2], "-c") != 0 && strcmp(argv[2], "-b") != 0) { 
        printf("Incorrect flag syntax... Exiting\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if((input = fopen(argv[3], "r+")) == NULL) { 
        printf("Input file could not be opened... Exiting\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        if(strcmp(argv[2], "-l") == 0) {
            line(input, output);
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[2], "-c") == 0) 
            cross(input, output);
        else {
            both(input, output, outputName);
        }
    } 
    printf("ran main: \n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char a, c;` Make that `int`. But your (eof) logic is still incorrect ...

Comment: I fixed the char to be int (Thanks for that), but what do you mean by the end of file is incorrect? when I run the program it outputs nothing and creates no files, I dont really understand what you mean.

Comment: Well, your logic is not incorrect, it is a bit *unusual*. You maintain a two-character memory by means of getc/ungetc. Normally you could maintain state (count number of consecutive '\n' s ...) Also the `if(lineNum > 9) 
                fprintf(output, "%d  ", ++lineNum);
            else 
                fprintf(output, "%d   ", ++lineNum);` looks kind of weird. And most people would use a `while(){...}` loop instead of your `do{...} while();` loop